# Click on NSCollectionView returns always the same object

Tags: objective-c, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I' ve a `NSCollectionViewItem` subclass, called `MyItem` used as item of my `NSCollectionView`. I need to enumerate all the item in my collection view to set the delegate for each item with this code:

```
NSUInteger categoryNumber = [self.collectionView.content count];

for (NSUInteger cont = 0;cont < categoryNumber;cont++)
{

    MyItem *categoryItem = (MyItem*)[self.collectionView itemAtIndex:cont];

    categoryItem.interactionDelegate = self;

}
```

Using the debugger I saw that this code works as I aspect and in each iteration the `MyItem` points to a different object each time. The problem is that when I use `mouseDown` event on my `MyItem` class I receive the same object whatever item i click on the `NSCollectionView`. It seems that the collection view use only one class (the cell template instance?). Anyone have an idea of what is going on? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in another part of my code and the `NSCOllectionView` returns, obviously, the correct object each time.